# Xcode 11 Simulator Crashing All the Time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

There is an app I'm working on. I use Xcode, and I haven't been able to test it.

Each time I launch the Xcode Simulator, it crashes, leaving me with the following message.

```
Details

The request to open "com.ecoleSourpHagop.everythingCOVID" failed.
Domain: FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain
Code: 5
Failure Reason: Unexpected error type.

User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = InvalidResponse;
}

--

The operation couldn’t be completed. (BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain error 3.)
Domain: BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain
Code: 3
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = OperationFailed;
}

--

System Information
macOS Version 10.15.4 (Build 19E287)
Xcode 11.4.1 (16137)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: First thing I would try is updating Xcode.

Comment: Does it tell you where in your code you get the error?

Comment: Will I lose my Xcode data if I update?

Comment: No, but you could always make a backup.